# Adobe Pro OCR for unscanned presentation with embedded text images

Tags: pdf, microsoft-powerpoint, ocr

I am trying to use Adobe Pro (2015)'s OCR capability to grab all of the text in a presentation. The presentation happens to be in PowerPoint. If I print the presentation and scan it, I can use Adobe to do OCR. However, I want to skip the print/scan step. I have tried converting the PowerPoint to a PDF. However, it seems that no matter what options I choose in creating the PDF, OCR fails to pick up text in the embedded images.

(At the risk of asking a second question:) The 'recognize text' option seems to work for the scanned document. When creating the pdf, is there a way to create it so that it behaves as if it were scanned? Or perhaps there's a more direct route to my problem?

Comment: Export the Powerpoint as jpeg. now you have "scans"

Comment: @Yorik Worked like a charm. If you add as an answer, I can give you the check.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Export the Powerpoint as jpeg. Now you have "scans" you can run through the OCR process.

Comment: With all due respect, but never, ever use JPEG when the document contains text. JPEG creates horrendous artefacts which can make OCR more difficult than needed, and which are visible and lead to mushy display. When the document to be OCRd contains (mainly) text, use TIFF.

Comment: I plus-one'd you, because it is true, however I was unsure if TIFF was an option for Powerpoint. In addition, most presentation slides have large-sized, non-running text where the JPEG compression noise is going to have a smaller impact on edge detection.

Comment: Actually, as Acrobat is present, it may be a better workflow to use the PowerPoint PDFMaker macro to create a PDF, and if OCR is still necessary, export to TIFF from Acrobat, and re-import.